# grails webflow wih jQuery form wizard not working

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp, formwizard, jquery-form-wizard

My application using `grails 2.2.0`. I am using grails webflow in user registration process. User registration process have two steps one personal information and another is payment information. This registration process and webflow is working fine.

Now I have asked to implement [formwizard](https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard) ([demo](http://thecodemine.org/#)) in the first step of the registration. Personal information step is now divide into two steps one is personal detail and another is address information.

When I add `form-wizard` class to implement the form-wizard view my webflow does not works, without `form-wizard` my web flow works fine.

I have added debug statements in the flow and found not log is printed when using `form-wizard`. I think my submit button behaviour changed in the `form-wizard`.

I have no idea how to fix the issue. How to use `grails webflow` with `form-wizard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many jQuery plugins was in my view, one of them was [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that was causing the issue. Once I removed this jQuery form plugin then my [jQuery form-wizard](http://thecodemine.org/#) works fine as explained in the [example](http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_20_submit_form_without_ajax.html).